# Deleting slices from numpy array given a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array *t_i* of shape (6, 2000, 2).
I need to delete column slices from the array if all the elements in that slice below that row is -1.
Let's say I am in ith row of t_i. Now for those columns below the ith row where every element in the column is [-1,-1] I need to delete the complete column slice from t_i.

I tried this:

```
t_iF = t_i[:, t_i[i+1:] != -1]
```

But I am getting this error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4
> were indexed

Can you all please point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Updated:
Let t_i be:

```
t1=np.arange(32).reshape(4,4,2)
t1[1:,[1,3]] = -1
```

In this case the whole 1 and 3 column slices need to be deleted.

Comment: Look at : `t_i[i+1:] != -1`.  That will give you a clue.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please add an example of source data and the expected result. Another problem is that your code looks rather like pseudo-code, e.g. value of *i* is unknown.

Comment: @adr, yes t_i[i+1:] != -1 returns a 3D tensor while I require only the column indices which satisfy the inequality. Can you suggest how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to add one. Actually I need to do this update over a loop(i.e. perform this step for a range of values of i). So i varies over a range. Thanks!

Comment: Define and input and output to go with the prose.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have added an example.

Comment: You haven't added an example, just some code. Make a 5x5 toy array that covers the basic cases, post it here, and show what you want it to look like after the code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) can be very helpful for tasks like these:

```py
import numpy as np

t1 = np.arange(32).reshape(4, 4, 2)
t1[1:, [1, 3]] = -1

t_filtered = t1[:, [np.any(t1[i, i:] != -1) for i in range(t1.shape[0])], :]
print(t_filtered.shape) # (4, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Hi @Stefan Thanks for the help. Actually its t1[1:,[1,3]] = -1 so we don't have the whole column slice as -1 instead we have all elements below a particular row in that slice as -1.

Comment: The problem description is still somewhat unclear. I have updated the answer now though, hoping this is what you need.